# Blocking within SLBufferQueueItf's callback

Tags: android-ndk, opensl

The OpenSL reference document does not answer whether it is possible to block within the callback specified by the call to *SLBufferQueueItf::RegisterCallback()*.

I am thinking to do this when the player signals that it is going to starve, and the data is not ready yet.

Answer (score 0):

According to [OpenSL ES programming notes](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/audio/opensl-prog-notes.html) for Android, callbacks should **never** block or perform excessive work. See *"Callbacks and Threads"* section.